# Update part of page on click with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to angular. If this is a duplicate, please post a link.

Ok, so I in javascript I have a list of items, lets say this:

```
[{
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 24,
},
{
    name: 'Smith',
    age: 56,
},
{
    name: 'Lisa',
    age: 12,
}]
```

All the `name` properties are printed out in a list at the left of the page, like this:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="person in persons">{{tournament.name}}</li>
```

All this works, but here is the thing.
When I click a person in the list, I want to display more detailed information to the right of the list about that person.

If I click on `Bob` in the list, it should display both `name` and `age` to the right of the list.

I can't figure this out in angular. Can anyone explain how I update a part of the page with that information?

Comment: They have a really great [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) that goes over the basics of this & many other topics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with a simple click on your li like that :

```
<ul data-ng-repeat="person in persons">
  <li ng-click="detail($index)">{{person.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

The $index is the index of the ng-repeat really useful to mange with arrays !

You add a div where you want to see the person details :

```
  <div>
    {{personDetail.name}} {{personDetail.age}} 
  </div>
```

In your controller implement the detail function like that :

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.persons = [{
                       name: 'Bob',
                       age: 24,
                    },
                    {
                       name: 'Smith',
                       age: 56,
                    },
                    {
                       name: 'Lisa',
                       age: 12,
                    }];

  $scope.detail = function(index){
      $scope.personDetail = $scope.persons[index];
  };

});
```

And voila !

working plnkr here : http://plnkr.co/edit/Wg4UD6?p=preview

Comment: yep, because its not something special, +1 for plunker

Answer (score 3):

```
<!-- left -->
<li data-ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-click="obj.selected=$index">
    {{person.name}}
</li>

<!-- right -->
<div>
    {{persons[obj.selected]["name"]}}
    {{persons[obj.selected]["age"]}}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.obj = {
    selected:-1
};
```

Comment: it works but i think that it's a little bit difficult for him when you see his question. You have probably to explain what is $index

Comment: @ThomasPons Thank you, but I know index.

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
 <li data-ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-click="clicked(person)">
```

**controller**

```
 $scope.selectedNode = "";
 ...
 $scope.clicked = function(info) {
    $scope.selectedNode = info;
};
```

now create right side:

```
<div>
  <pre>{{selectedNode | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: It's fun to see how we can do the same thing in so much different ways