# Select Filter dont work properly, Angular js ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

**Hi there,**
I am new to angular.
In my current demo app I created some users list with select filter ng-option.
there is some bug that I didn't mange to find.
The bug:
When I choosing the Female it filters ok and shows me only Female users
 But when I choosing
the Male option it shows me full list and don't filtering the Female users.
here is my code:
html-page:

```
  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
    <div class="col-lg-2 divPad">
        <!--Sidebar content-->
        <b>Sort by gender:</b>
          <select ng-model="query.gender" class="btn btn-default" >
                  <option value="">All users</option>
                  <option ng-repeat="gender in genders" value="{{gender}}">{{gender}}</option>
              </select>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
        <div class="col-lg-2 divPad">
            <b>Sort by Hobbies:</b>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="query.hobby" >
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul class="phones">
            <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:query "  class="thumbnail phone-listing">
                <a href="#/users/{{user.name}}" class="thumb">
                    <img style="margin-top: 15px;" ng-src="{{user.imageUrl}}"></a>
                <a href="#/users/{{user.name}}">{{user.name}}</a>
                <p><b>Hobby:</b>&nbsp;{{user.hobby}}</p>
                 <p><b>Gender:</b>&nbsp;{{user.gender}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

the controller-page:

```
    zenvaControllers.controller('UserListCtrl', ['$scope', 'User', function ($scope, User) {
    $scope.users = User.query();
    $scope.genders = ["Male", "Female"];
}]);
```

json-page:

```
  [
    {
        "name": "Lucy",
        "gender": "Female",
        "hobby": "pets",
        "imageUrl": "img/users/avatar1.png"

    },
    {
        "name": "Betty",
        "gender": "Female",
        "hobby": "pets",
         "imageUrl": "img/users/avatar2.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ronald",
        "gender": "Male",
        "hobby": "music",
        "imageUrl": "img/users/avatar3.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "Christopher",
        "gender": "Male",
        "hobby": "sports",
        "imageUrl": "img/users/avatar4.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ximena",
        "gender": "Female",
        "hobby": "reading",
        "imageUrl": "img/users/avatar5.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "Paul",
        "gender": "Male",
        "hobby": "shopping",
         "imageUrl": "img/users/avatar6.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "Charlie",
        "gender": "Male",
        "hobby": "pets",
       "imageUrl": "img/users/avatar7.png"
    }
]
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Use custom filter, see example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/3nZYxDOLnsV1Zk7YS5Mm?p=preview

Comment: Thanks it working with check-box solution,But Still what is wrong with my drop-down filter?

Answer (score 0):

I would write two custom filters that should take care for both cases:

`hobbyFilter` and `genderFilter`

Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gNkj0w0MUxPULeXstqwe?p=preview)**</kbd>

```
iApp.filter('hobbyFilter', function() {
   return function( items, query) {
    var filtered = [];


    if(query.hobby === undefined || query.hobby === ''){
      return items;
    }

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      console.log(item.gender, query.gender);
      if(
        query.hobby !== undefined &&
        query.hobby !== '' &&
        item.hobby.indexOf(query.hobby) >= 0)
        {
          filtered.push(item);
        }
    });

    return filtered;
  };
});


 iApp.filter('genderFilter', function() {
   return function( items, query) {

    var filtered = [];


    if(query.gender === undefined || query.gender === ''){
      return items;
    }

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {

      if(item.gender === query.gender){
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });

    return filtered;
  };
});
```

**Usage**

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users |  genderFilter:query |  hobbyFilter:query">
```

Comment: Hi Maxim, I have one more question in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982900/update-part-of-page-on-click-with-angularjs  there is solution to show name of user/person when click on it but, in my last discussed demo app I have filters so when I filter males or females the index got wrong. for example: when I show only males gender and click on it first li it shows me the first name of the my users array(lucy)  and not some male name. what I should to add to solve this issue

Comment: @MishaBeskin will be fine if you can reproduce the issue in fiddle or plunker.

Comment: Hi Max, here is my demo app on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hGJInjSde7vSGGcbTrQL?p=preview

Comment: @MishaBeskin Generally is not good way to ask different question under old one. I would create new question, because SO solves not only solo problem but it helps to others. Further, I would accept above mentioned example (if it works for you) Anyways here is a working link: http://plnkr.co/edit/xGsgAdIDUgGY9jgiDkoJ?p=preview   What I did: pass instead `$index` the `user` model. This is a right way. Enjoy